# elasticsearch plugin install SSLHandshakeException

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, sslhandshakeexception

I'm working on an **Ubuntu VM**, with a **proxy**.
I have this error then i try to install an **elasticsearch plugin** :

```
bin/plugin install --verbose license
-Dhttp.proxyHost=https://myusername:mypassword@my.url.proxy
-Dhttp.proxyPort=portnum -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

-> Installing license...
Trying
  https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/license/2.2.0/license-2.2.0.zip
...

Failed: SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake]; nested: EOFException[SSL peer shut down incorrectly]; 

ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

with or without the options **-Dhttp.proxyHost**, **-Dhttp.proxyPort** and **-Dhttps.protocols**, i have the same problem.

Any help will be appreciated,

Christophe